# How to pass the map as an immutable map?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, maps

I have a `map` defined as follows:

```
typedef std::map<AsnIdentifier, AsnValue, AsnComparator> MibMap;
```

I have one such map and I want to pass it to another function such that the function to which it is passed cannot modify it.

```
void someFunc() {
   MibMap someMap = GetMibMap();
   otherFunc(someMap);
}
```

And the signature of `otherFunc` could be as follows for immutability:

```
void otherFunc(const MibMap& someMap);
```

But as soon as use `find` function of the map, I get a pretty verbose compilation error.

```
void otherFunc(const MibMap& someMap) {
   MibMap::iterator findVal = someMap.find(//pass the key to find);  //this does not compile
}
```

As soon as I remove `const` from the method signature the compilation error goes away. What is the reason for it? I want to keep the map unmodifiable but at the same time I am unsure of this compilation error.

**Edit**: The compilation error is like:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Tree_const_iterator... (and a whole long list)
```

Comment: Reading compilation errors is an invaluable programmer skill, and you should work on it. The "whole long list" actually contains the solution to your problem, as (somewhat buried in template arguments), the actual message the compiler is trying to say is "cannot convert from `some_const_iterator` to `some_iterator`." If you learn to mentally parse the errors, it will help you.

Comment: For a `const std::map`, `find` returns a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator` and a `const_iterator` cannot be implicitly converted to an `iterator`.   Change the type of `findVal` accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at suitable [reference documentation for `std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), you will see the it has two overloads which differ in 1. the const-qualification of the implicit `this` parameter, and 2. the return type:

```
iterator find( const Key& key );
const_iterator find( const Key& key ) const;
```

From here, your problem should be obvious: you're calling the `const`-qualified `find`, but you're trying to convert its result into `MibMap::iterator`. Change the type of `findVal` to `const_iterator` (or just use `auto`) and it will work.